# Residential Proxies disappearing while webscraping

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, amazon-ec2, proxy, fetch

I have created a application witch uses residential proxies for webscraping. Everything worked fine  when I had it on my localhost.

The proxies got used on the websites I was calling. But when I switched to an ec2 instance on AWS my proxies started to get used up even when I wasn't using them for requests.

I could sleep one night and all the traffic I paid for was gone. And it was all on a nuch of bullshit websites that I would never visit or send requests to. I have tried with multiple proxy providers and I get the same issue.

My theory is that the connection stays open when the requests fail and then get used for other clients. But I don't know. Does anyone have a solution?

```
const proxyAgent = new HttpsProxyAgent(
            "http://XXXXX:XXXXX@geo.iproyal.com:12321"
          );
          response = await fetch(
            "https://www.google.com/",
            {
              signal: Timeout(20).signal,
              agent: proxyAgent,

              headers: {
                "User-agent":
                  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
              },
            }
          );
          response = await response.text();
```

[Picture of the proxy traffic that i get. (All these websites I have not touched)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jimfj.jpg)

I have tried multiple proxy providers and multiple fetch node js libraries but nothing has worked.

Comment: Assuming your theory is correct, it would be quite a big security issue: You can watch others traffic and others can use your data bandwith. Do you think others use your proxy over AWS, or directly ?

Comment: I think they use it over AWS. But I am not sure. I think the proxy connection somehow is kept with the server and used by other. But again I have no idea and are open to other sugestions